# A bit of guidance on making an application for a website

Tags: android, session, webview

I am starting to develop an application that uses the same facilities of the webpage, but in an android mobile application. I am using Java on Eclipse with Android SDK and I am wondering what is the smartest way to go about this.

The website contains a login and it also has a facility to access a web drive (like google drive).

Q1) Should I use JSoup to load the webpages in a webview on the app? And if so how do I go about controlling the login and sessions? IF NOT, what is a good way to go about doing this?

Q2) Is it possible to include a web drive in a webview? I've tried searching around for an answer to this but I couldn't find much. I want the user to be able to access it after logging in so they can download their files to their phone.

Usually wouldn't post a question without any code but I've got so many mixed answers I'm not too sure what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Forget about JSOUP. `WebView` is able to directly load the website from a remote URL as well as from a local version (stored under `assets/`).

Q2) "Include a drive in a `webview`"? `Webview` is just a browser. you can "include" whatever you want, meaning just loading a URL as you would do with Chrome

If you have not much experience with Android, the easiest approach would be just to develop your website in your server as usual (targeting mobile devices of course and using the Chrome Developer Tools to simulate the mobile screen), then just load this URL in `Webview`. Later on you can include other techniques like storing parts of the website into the application assets, or even store the whole webapp as a local website. That may require some (little) coding to handle cookies and https certificates, and adjusting the webapp to run locally but it's nothing very hard and there's extensive documentation here in StackOverflow.